# How to save sensor data output into Microsoft access using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I'm currently working with raspberry pi and using DHT11 to read temperature and humidity values every second. I have to save these values into a database in real time. Here's my code that showing sensor data every second. I don't know how to save the data/result in Microsoft Access.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime
import os


# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=dht11_pin)

    while True:

        cnt += 1
        if cnt%limit_sec == 0 or cnt == 1:

            result = instance.read()
            if result.is_valid():

                if previous_temperature != result.temperature or previous_humidity != result.humidity:

                    previous_temperature = result.temperature
                    previous_humidity = result.humidity

                    counter += 1
                    rightnow = datetime.datetime.now()

                    if result.humidity>=40:
                        print(str(counter)+". Last valid input: " )
                        print("Date: " + rightnow.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
                        print("Time: " + rightnow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                        print("Status: Your plant is on the good condition.")
                        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
                        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)
                        print("*******************************************")


                    else:
                        print(str(counter)+". Last valid input: " )
                        print("Date: " + rightnow.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
                        print("Time: " + rightnow.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                        print("Status: Your plant is on the bad condition. Please open the water supply.")
                        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
                        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)
                        print("*******************************************")

            else:
                print "Invalid result!"
                pass

        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Comment: Python has to open a connection to Access and execute INSERT action SQL. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320509/python-pyodbc-connect-to-ms-access-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757873/connect-to-ms-access-in-python

Comment: thank you for your help.